# Emacs hide some of the documents in Typescript

Tags: lsp, outline-mode

I'm using Doom emacs. I developing an App in Typescript. I just encounter a strange behavior of Emacs that compact the description of lsp-buffer like in the image below. Does anyone know how to disable this feature as I need to see all the fields of the object that I'm working with? Thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: Are the numbers links perhaps that you can click to expand the item?

Comment: I tried. Clicking and press Tab at the hidden area and number indicator. It does not expand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Volar lsp to developing Vue web app.
I found out I have the same result using VSCode. Therefore it must be the result from the language server not related to Emacs.